# Custom ListView left and right alignment for sports events

Tags: android, listview, android-recyclerview

Apologies about the title gore as this is a question I found difficult to word. In my application, I retrieve match data from live football/soccer matches and I would like to list the events of these matches differently dependent on it being for the local team or visitor teams.

Many applications achieve what I would like to do but I can't seem to find a simple explanation.

An image of similar to what I'd like to achieve:

[image]

Comment: make both items in layout one for right and one for left in single xml which part do you want to show set visiblity show of that side left or right and set visibility gone of otherside

Comment: I honestly do believe that sometimes you need someone to state the obvious to you. Thanks for your help, I can't believe I didn't think of something as simple as that. Although other methods are still appreciated

Comment: Actually there is a better way to achieve what you want. ListView and RecyclerView have a itemView functionality which allow you to have couple different layout styles in one list